# Opengl: Lighten object when viewing from almost parallel to the surface

Tags: opengl

I have made a wind turbine structure (picture 1) in opengl.

My problem is that when I rotate it and view it from the tip of one of the blades (picture 2), then the blade becomes so dark that I cannot see the details. I have tried different light and material settings, but haven't found settings that makes it better and am therefore back at the default settings.

How can I make the details more appear more clear?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Almost all lighting models do not depend on the angle between the viewer and the surface, but on the angle between light and surface.

Comment: @BDL what? To my knowledge, almost all lighting models depend on both angles. How else would you get e.g. specular highlights when moving the camera around an object?

Comment: It seems that your light is colocated with the camera. Place some static lights in the scene to avoid the darkening.

Comment: @ArttuPeltonen Yeah, I should have written it clearer: Diffuse illumination (as shown in the images) should not depend on the viewing angle. Thanks for the hint :)